# Is it possible to add 2nd slug to URL path in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-2.0, django-2.1

I'm using Django version 2.1.

I want to create this type of URL Path in my Project:
www.example.com/bachelor/germany/university-of-frankfurt/corporate-finance

Is it possible to do it in Django?

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible. URLs can be whatever you want.

Comment: could you show me the way to do it? I can only one slug to URL Path.

Comment: @UlviDamirli: what problems do you face with "generalizing" this for two slugs?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, say for example that you have a slug for an `Author`, and one for a `Book`, you can define it as:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from app.views import book_details

urlpatterns = [
    path('book/<slug:author_slug>/<slug:book_slug>/', book_details),
]
```

Then the view looks like:

```
# app/views.py

from django.http import HttpResponse

def book_details(request, author_slug, book_slug):
    # ...
    return HttpResponse()
```

The view thus takes two extra parameters `author_slug` (the slug for the author), and `book_slug` (the slug for the book).

If you thus query for `/book/shakespeare/romeo-and-juliet`, then `author_slug` will contains `'shakespeare'`, and `book_slug` will contain `'romeo-and-juliet'`.

We can for example look up that specific book with:

```
def book_details(request, author_slug, book_slug):
    my_book = Book.objects.get(author__slug=author_slug, slug=book_slug)
    return HttpResponse()
```

Or in a `DetailView`, by overriding the [**`get_object(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object):

```
class BookDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Book

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        super(BookDetailView, self).get_object(queryset=queryset)
        return qs.get(
            author__slug=self.kwargs['author_slug'],
            slug=self.kwargs['book_slug']
        )
```

or for all views (including the `DetailView`), by overriding the `get_queryset` method:

```
class BookDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Book

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(BookDetailView, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(
            author__slug=self.kwargs['author_slug'],
            slug=self.kwargs['book_slug']
        )
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for your answer. It helped me a lot. Is it possible to do it with Generic Detail View? If yes, how?

Comment: You can see my code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237787/how-to-add-multiple-slugs-into-one-url-path-in-django-2-1

Comment: @UlviDamirli: yes, in the hypothetical answer, the `Book` has a foreign key `author`, to an `Author` class that contains a slug. So if you have a reference, you can use double underscores, like you normally do with Django filtering.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem this answer is helpful, but how to i now pass the slug in my template url tag e.g <a hred{% url 'url_name' slug1 slug2 %}>, how should this be done, that is my problem now? please help me

Comment: You can pass the parameters in the above case like this: 
<a href="{% url 'book_details' author_slug= authorObj.slug  book_slug = bookObj.slug  %}"> View book </a>