# RedirectView give NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, redirect, django-views, django-urls, django-2.1

[Recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206342/combining-more-than-one-slug-in-the-url) I've changed the paths of the blog posts to give more legible the urls.

**Before** I've this paths:

```
path("category/<slug:slug_category>/", views.singleCategory_postList, name="single_category"),
path("<slug:slug_post>/", views.singlePost, name='single_blog_post'),
```

**Now** I've this:

```
path("<slug:slug_category>/", views.singleCategory_postList, name="single_category"),
path("<slug:slug_category>/<slug:slug_post>/", views.singlePost, name='single_blog_post'),
```

**Before** get_absolute_url was this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
.....
    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse("single_category", kwargs={"slug_category": self.slug_category})


class BlogPost(ModelPost, TimeManager):
.....
    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse("single_blog_post", kwargs={"slug_post": self.slug_post})
```

**Now** is this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
.....
def get_absolute_url(self): 
    return reverse("single_category", kwargs={"slug_category": self.slug_category})


class BlogPost(ModelPost, TimeManager):
.....
def get_absolute_url(self): 
    return reverse("single_blog_post", kwargs={
                                            "slug_post": self.slug_post,
                                            "slug_category": self.category.slug_category,
                                            })
```

I'm trying to use the *RedirectView* for redirect all the old paths; then into *urls.py* I've this now:

```
path("category/<slug:slug_category>/", RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='single_category', permanent=True)),
path("<slug:slug_post>/", RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='single_blog_post', permanent=True)),

path("categorie/", views.categoryList, name="list_category"),
path("<slug:slug_category>/", views.singleCategory_postList, name="single_category"),

path("", views.postList, name='list_post'),
path("<slug:slug_category>/<slug:slug_post>/", views.singlePost, name='single_blog_post'),
```

When I use those RedirectView it's shown me this error:

> NoReverseMatch at /blog/gis/
>
> Reverse for 'single_blog_post' with keyword arguments '{'slug_post':
>   'gis'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['blog\/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\/$']

If I comment the two RedirectView paths the error disappear and I can use the site without problems but when I use the old paths I see 404 error.

I don't have understood how RedirectView works. Someone can give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your old view only required the post slug, but your new one additionally requires the category slug. However, there's no way a simple RedirectView can do this redirection, because it can only look at the arguments passed in the original URL itself. It doesn't know how to go to the database to find the category slug and use it in the redirection.

So, you'll need to write the redirect view yourself. It could be pretty simple:

```
def redirect_with_category(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    return redirect(post, permanent=True)
```

Note that [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) will automatically call the `get_absolute_url` method of the Post. Also note you want to use `permanent=True` to return a 301 rather than a 302.

Comment: Need I to create a function based view alike yours and a path for that function? I've understood? Did I get it right?

Comment: You need to reference this view in your urls.py instead of the RedirectView for single_blog_post.

Comment: Something like this?

**views.py**
`class OldPathBlogPost(RedirectView):

    pattern_name = 'single_blog_post'

    def redirect_old_blogpost(request, slug_post):
        blogpost = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug_post=slug_post)
        return redirect(blogpost, permanent=True)`  

**urls.py**
`path("<slug:slug_post>/", views.OldPathBlogPost.as_view()),` I've 404 error. I think that this is to hard for my actual competence. I've started to learn Django last summer...

Comment: No. Why do you want to change the code I gave you? Just take that exact code, and in urls.py do `path("<slug:slug_post>/", views.redirect_with_category)`.

Comment: I've change your redirect_with_category because I thought it was a generic example and because there isn't a model named _Post_ but I've _BlogPost_ .  However I've used your view and your path but I see Page Not Found if I try to go at **/blog/rete-dei-sottoservizi-quadro-normativo/** instead of **/blog/gis/rete-dei-sottoservizi-quadro-normativo/**